# How can I learn about parser combinators?

Tags: parsing, monads

I've found a few resources on the subject, but they all require a deep understanding of [SmallTalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) or [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29), neither of which I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some parser combinator libraries in more mainstream languages:

- [Spirit](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) (C++)
- [Jparsec](http://jparsec.codehaus.org/) (Java)

Comment: Link for Jparsec is broken.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote 8 longish blog entries on monadic parser combinators in C# and F#; see [here](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!123.entry) for the first one.

See also [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) (Parsec for F#)

Answer (score 4):

There are some great articles on the web describing parser combinators in C#, but no maintainable source repository, so I've created one at:

http://code.google.com/p/sprache/

Someone knowledgeable about parser combinators could probably do a lot to improve it (please step forward if this sounds like you :))

Answer (score 3):

If you know Python, there's [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Answer (score 3):

For me [this](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/monparsing.ps) paper was extremly useful. It is almost languange neutral. Just in some small places they are reffering to [Gofer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gofer_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: you probably mean GOFER http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gofer_%28programming_language%29

Answer (score 2):

I found [an interesting article about implementing a parser combinator in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/lukeh/archive/2007/08/19/monadic-parser-combinators-using-c-3-0.aspx). It also references some more general papers on the subject.

[The Wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_Combinator) also has a general explaination of the concept.

Answer (score 2):

Chrise Double wrote [a parser combinator in Javascript](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/2007/10/javascript-parser-combinators.html).

Answer (score 1):

<s>Cay Horstmann has [4 combinator parser lectures in Scala](http://horstmann.com/sjsu/cs152/schedule.html), with exercises.</s> There is an example of parsing external DSLs in Scala [here](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2008/04/external-dsls-made-easy-with-scala.html).

Comment: I'm getting 404 on the first link. Please, renew if this is possible. (Yep, i knew that this was 3 years ago).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/grads/l/lorgon/Talks/MonPar/monpar.html) is a link to a talk (slides and script) on monadic parser combinators in C++.

Comment: Link is apparently deleted.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/the-magic-behind-parser-combinators